# Only part of form is saved upon validation error

Tags: python, django

I am trying to eliminate the loss of data upon page refresh when validation fails.  When the form is refreshed after validation error, all the fields are empty, except for the fields in the  that caused the error.  How can I have the page refresh, display the validation errors and still have all the fields in all the divs populated?

Thanks in advance!

My code is displayed below:

views.py

```
class CreateListingView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'listing/listing.html'
    model = Listing
    form_class = ListingForm
    # success_url = '/add-listing/'

def get_success_url(self):
    return reverse('store') + "?success=true"

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
        if not self.request.user.has_company():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('get_paid'))
        elif not self.request.user.has_shipping():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('get_paid'))
        elif not self.request.user.has_bank():
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('get_paid'))
        else:
            return super(CreateListingView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('create_user'))

def get_initial(self):
    return {'company_profile': self.request.user.company}

def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(CreateListingView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    if self.request.method in ('POST', 'PUT'):
        kwargs['data']['price'] = kwargs['data']['price'].replace(',','')
    return kwargs
```

forms.py

```
class ListingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    caliber_firearm = forms.CharField(required=False,     widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'req'}))
    caliber_ammo = forms.CharField(required=False)

tags = forms.CharField(required=False)
img_0 = forms.ImageField(required=False, widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'image-input'}))
img_1 = forms.ImageField(required=False, widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'image-input'}))
img_2 = forms.ImageField(required=False, widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'image-input'}))
img_3 = forms.ImageField(required=False, widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'image-input'}))
img_4 = forms.ImageField(required=False, widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'image-input'}))

class Meta:
    model = Listing
    exclude = ['copy', 'caliber']
    widgets = {
        'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'title-listing'}),
        'listing_type': forms.RadioSelect(),
        'upc': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'upc'}),
        'category': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'short-input', 'required': 'True'}),
        'price': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'price dollar req'}),
        'list_price': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'list_price_input'}),
        'quantity': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'qty req'}),
        'description': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'description req'}),
        'estimated_ship_days': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'qty req', 'placeholder': 'Days'}),
        'capacity': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'req'}),
        'weight_pounds': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'weight req', 'placeholder': 'Pounds'}),
        'weight_ounces': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'weight', 'placeholder': 'Ounces'}),
        'barrel_length': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'req', 'placeholder': 'Inches'}),
        'overall_length': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'req', 'placeholder': 'Inches'}),
        'company_profile': forms.HiddenInput(),
        'shipping_zip_code': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your shipping zip code'}),
    }

    error_messages = empty_errors

def clean(self):
    listing_type = self.cleaned_data.get('listing_type')
    if self.cleaned_data.get('img_0') is None and \
                    self.cleaned_data.get('img_1') is None and \
                    self.cleaned_data.get('img_2') is None and \
                    self.cleaned_data.get('img_3') is None and \
                    self.cleaned_data.get('img_4') is None:

        self.add_error('img_0', 'One photo must be uploaded')

    if listing_type == 'Firearm':
        if self.cleaned_data.get('caliber_firearm', None) is None:
            self.add_error('caliber_firearm', 'This field is required')
        else:
            self.cleaned_data['caliber'] = self.cleaned_data.get('caliber_firearm')
        if self.cleaned_data.get('capacity', None) is None:
            self.add_error('capacity', 'This field is required')
        if self.cleaned_data.get('weight_pounds', None) is None:
            self.add_error('weight_pounds', 'This field is required')
        if self.cleaned_data.get('weight_ounces', None) is None:
            self.add_error('weight_ounces', 'This field is required')
        if self.cleaned_data.get('barrel_length', None) is None:
            self.add_error('barrel_length', 'This field is required')
        if self.cleaned_data.get('overall_length', None) is None:
            self.add_error('overall_length', 'This field is required')
    elif listing_type == 'Ammo':
        if self.cleaned_data.get('caliber_ammo', None) is not None:
            self.cleaned_data['caliber'] = self.cleaned_data.get('caliber_ammo')

    if self.cleaned_data.get('shipping_zip_code') is None or \
                    self.cleaned_data.get('shipping_weight') is None or \
                    self.cleaned_data.get('shipping_height') is None or \
                    self.cleaned_data.get('shipping_length') is None or \
                    self.cleaned_data.get('shipping_width') is None:

        self.add_error('shipping_weight', 'Shipping information is not complete')

    return self.cleaned_data
```

Template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block head %}

    <title>Dealer Direct by FFL Design</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          type="text/css"
          href="{% static 'listing/css/listing.css' %}">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'listing/js/listing.js' %}"></script>

    <!-- Start of ffldesign Zendesk Widget script -->
    <script>/*<![CDATA[*/window.zEmbed||function(e,t){var n,o,d,i,s,a=[],r=document.createElement("iframe");window.zEmbed=function(){a.push(arguments)},window.zE=window.zE||window.zEmbed,r.src="javascript:false",r.title="",r.role="presentation",(r.frameElement||r).style.cssText="display: none",d=document.getElementsByTagName("script"),d=d[d.length-1],d.parentNode.insertBefore(r,d),i=r.contentWindow,s=i.document;try{o=s}catch(c){n=document.domain,r.src='javascript:var d=document.open();d.domain="'+n+'";void(0);',o=s}o.open()._l=function(){var o=this.createElement("script");n&&(this.domain=n),o.id="js-iframe-async",o.src=e,this.t=+new Date,this.zendeskHost=t,this.zEQueue=a,this.body.appendChild(o)},o.write('<body onload="document._l();">'),o.close()}("https://assets.zendesk.com/embeddable_framework/main.js","ffldesign.zendesk.com");/*]]>*/</script>
    <!-- End of ffldesign Zendesk Widget script --> 

{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<body>
    <div class="listing">
        <p class="ffl">Add a new listing</p>
        <form action="{% url 'add-listing' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="errors">{{ form.shipping_weight.errors }}</div>
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="photos">
                <p class="ffl-small">Photos</p>
                <p class="desc" id="photos-desc">Must add at least one photo.</p>
                <ul>
                    <li id="photo_0">
                        <div id="input_photo_0">
                            <img src="{% static 'listing/images/add-photo.png' %}" class="add-photo">
                            <p><button type="button" class="active-button">Add Photo</button></p>
                            {{ form.img_0 }}
                        </div>
                        <div id="display_photo_0" class="hidden">
                            <img src="" width="143" height="105" id="img_view_0" class="item-image">
                            <button type="button" class="remove-zoom active-button magnify"><img src="{% static 'listing/images/zoom.png' %}" width="18" height="18"></button><button type="button" class="remove-zoom active-button delete_photo"><img src="{% static 'listing/images/remove.png' %}"></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="photo_1">
                        <div id="input_photo_1">
                            <img src="{% static 'listing/images/add-photo.png' %}" class="add-photo">
                            <p><button type="button" class="active-button">Add Photo</button></p>
                            {{ form.img_1 }}
                        </div>
                        <div id="display_photo_1" class="hidden">
                            <img src="" width="143" height="105" id="img_view_1" class="item-image">
                            <button type="button" class="remove-zoom active-button magnify"><img src="{% static 'listing/images/zoom.png' %}" width="18" height="18"></button><button type="button" class="remove-zoom active-button delete_photo"><img src="{% static 'listing/images/remove.png' %}"></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="photo_2">
                        <div id="input_photo_2">
                            <img src="{% static 'listing/images/add-photo.png' %}" class="add-photo">
                            <p><button type="button" class="active-button">Add Photo</button></p>
                            {{ form.img_2 }}
                        </div>
                        <div id="display_photo_2" class="hidden">
                            <img src="" width="143" height="105" id="img_view_2" class="item-image">
                            <button type="button" class="remove-zoom active-button magnify"><img src="{% static 'listing/images/zoom.png' %}" width="18" height="18"></button><button type="button" class="remove-zoom active-button delete_photo"><img src="{% static 'listing/images/remove.png' %}"></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="photo_3">
                        <div id="input_photo_3">
                            <img src="{% static 'listing/images/add-photo.png' %}" class="add-photo">
                            <p><button type="button" class="active-button">Add Photo</button></p>
                            {{ form.img_3 }}
                        </div>
                        <div id="display_photo_3" class="hidden">
                            <img src="" width="143" height="105" id="img_view_3" class="item-image">
                            <button type="button" class="remove-zoom active-button magnify"><img src="{% static 'listing/images/zoom.png' %}" width="18" height="18"></button><button type="button" class="remove-zoom active-button delete_photo"><img src="{% static 'listing/images/remove.png' %}"></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li id="photo_4">
                        <div id="input_photo_4">
                            <img src="{% static 'listing/images/add-photo.png' %}" class="add-photo">
                            <p><button type="button" class="active-button">Add Photo</button></p>
                            {{ form.img_4 }}
                        </div>
                        <div id="display_photo_4" class="hidden">
                            <img src="" width="143" height="105" id="img_view_4" class="item-image">
                            <button type="button" class="remove-zoom active-button magnify"><img src="{% static 'listing/images/zoom.png' %}" width="18" height="18"></button><button type="button" class="remove-zoom active-button delete_photo"><img src="{% static 'listing/images/remove.png' %}"></button>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="desc">
                        For best results, use high quality jpeg or gif files that are at least 570 px wide.
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="select-type">
                <p class="ffl-small">Select listing type</p>
                {% for radio in form.listing_type %}
                    {{ radio }}
                {% endfor %}
{#                <label><input type="radio" name="listing" checked>Firearms</label>#}
{#                <label><input type="radio" name="listing">Ammo</label>#}
{#                <label><input type="radio" name="listing">Optics</label>#}
{#                <label><input type="radio" name="listing">Apparel</label>#}
{#                <label><input type="radio" name="listing">Other</label>#}
            </div>
            <div class="details">
                <p class="ffl-small">Listing Details</p>
                <p><label for="id_title">Title<span>&#42;</span></label><input type="text" id="id_title" name="title" class="title-listing" required><span class="desc">Describe your item using words and phrases people would use in a search.</span>
                    <span class="title-error">Error: you cannot use a period in the title name.</span>
                </p>
                <p><label for="id_upc">UPC</label><input type="text" name="upc" id="id_upc" class="upc" maxlength="12"></p>
                <p><label for="id_category">Category<span>&#42;</span></label>
                    {{form.category}}
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="id_price">Cost<span>&#42;</span></label><input type="number" name="price" id="id_price" class="price dollar req" min=0 step="0.01">
                    <span class="list_price_text">List Price:<input type="number" name="list_price" id="id_list_price" class="list_price_input" step="0.01" readonly></span>
                    <span class="list_price_desc">The "List Price" is automatically calculated with Dealer Direct seller fees. This price is what the dealer will see. The "Cost" field is the amount you will be paid.</span>
                </p>
                <p><label for="id_quantity">Quantity<span>&#42;</span></label><input type="text" name="quantity" id="id_quantity" class="qty req"></p>
                <p><label for="id_description" class="textarea-label">Description<span>&#42;</span></label><textarea name="description" id="id_description" class="description req"></textarea></p>
                <p><label for="id_estimated_ship_days">Days to ship:<span>&#42;</span></label><input type="text" name="estimated_ship_days" id="id_estimated_ship_days" class="qty req" placeholder="days"></p>

                {% for field in form.hidden_fields %}
                    {{ field }}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="details ammo type-ammo">
                <p class="ffl-small">Ammo Details</p>
                <p><label for="id_rounds">Rounds per box</label>{{ form.rounds }}</p>
                <p><label for="id_caliber_ammo">Caliber/Gauge</label>{{ form.caliber_ammo }}</p>
                <p><label for="id_weight">Weight</label>{{ form.weight }}</p>
                <p><label for="id_muzzle_velocity">Muzzle Velocity</label>{{ form.muzzle_velocity }}</p>
                <p><label for="id_length">Length</label>{{ form.length }}</p>
                <p><label for="id_ammo_type">Type</label>{{ form.ammo_type }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="details ammo type-firearm">
                <p class="ffl-small">Firearm Details</p>
                <p><label for="id_caliber_firearm">Caliber<span>&#42;</span></label>{{ form.caliber_firearm }}</p>
                <p><label for="id_capacity">Capacity<span>&#42;</span></label>{{ form.capacity }}</p>
                <p><label for="id_weight_pounds">Weight<span>&#42;</span></label>{{ form.weight_pounds }}<label for="id_weight_ounces" class="weight-label"></label>{{ form.weight_ounces }}</p>
                <p><label for="id_barrel_length">Barrel Length<span>&#42;</span></label>{{ form.barrel_length }}</p>
                <p><label for="id_overall_length">Overall Length<span>&#42;</span></label>{{ form.overall_length }}</p>
                <p><label for="id_finish">Finish</label>{{ form.finish }}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="details optics type-optics">
                <p class="ffl-small">Optics Details</p>
                <p><label for="id_magnification">Magnification</label><input id="id_magnification" name="magnification" type="text"></p>
                <p><label for="id_field_of_view">Field of View</label><input id="id_field_of_view" name="field_of_view" type="text"></p>
                <p><label for="id_reticle">Reticle</label><input id="id_reticle" name="reticle" type="text"></p>
                <p><label for="id_objective_lens">Objective Lens</label><input id="id_objective_lens" name="objective_lens" type="text"></p>
                <p><label for="id_eye_relief">Eye Relief</label><input id="id_eye_relief" name="eye_relief" type="text"></p>
                <p><label for="id_max_elevation_adjustment">Max Elevation Adjustment</label><input id="id_max_elevation_adjustment" name="max_elevation_adjustment" type="text"></p>
                <p><label for="id_max_windage_adjustment">Max Windage<br/>Adjustment</label><input id="id_max_windage_adjustment" name="max_windage_adjustment" type="text"></p>
                <p><label for="id_length_optics">Length</label><input id="id_length_optics" name="length" type="text"></p>
                <p><label for="id_weight_optics">Weight</label><input id="id_weight_optics" name="weight" type="text"></p>
                <p><label for="id_battery">Battery</label><input id="id_battery" name="battery" type="text"></p>
                <p><label for="id_dot_size">DOT Size</label><input id="id_dot_size" name="dot_size" type="text"></p>
                <p><label for="id_finish_optics">Finish</label><input id="id_finish_optics" name="finish" type="text"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="details apparel type-apparel">
                <p class="ffl-small">Apparel Details</p>
                <p><label for="id_shirt_size">Size</label>
                    {{ form.shirt_size }}
                </p>
                <p><label for="id_shirt_color">Color</label><input id="id_shirt_color" name="shirt_color" type="text"></p>
            </div>
            <div class="search">
                <p class="ffl-small">Search Terms</p>
                <p class="desc">Help dealers find this product by using accurate and descriptive words or phrases.</p>
                <ul class="search-ul">
                    <li>
                        <span class="tags"><label for="id_tags">Tags</label></span>
                        <span class="desc">Optional</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label><input type="text" name="tags" id="id_tags" placeholder="example: ar15, iron sights, glock holster, etc" class="tag-input"><span class="desc left">10 left</span></label>
                        <p class="tags-wrapper">must separate each tag by a comma</p>
                        <p id="tag-list"></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span class="desc">
                            We highly recommend using all 10 tags for<br />your listing to get
                            found. Use words you think<br />dealers would use to search for this product.
                        </span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class=" details shipping">
                <p class="ffl-small">Shipping</p>
                <p class="desc">For realistic shipping expectations, please provide accurate product shipping information below.</p>
                <div class="errors">{{ form.shipping_zip_code.errors }}{{ form.shipping_weight.errors }}</div>
                {% comment %}
                <p class="zip"><label for="">Zip Code</label><input name="" type="text" placeholder="Your shipping zip code"></p>
                <p class="shipping-weight"><label for="">Weight</label><input name="" type="text"><label for=""></label><input name="" type="text"></p>
                <p class="dimensions"><label for="">Dimensions</label><input name="" type="text"><label for=""></label><input name="" type="text"><label for=""></label><input name="" type="text"></p>
                {% endcomment %}
                <p class="zip">
                    <label for="id_shipping_zip_code">Zip Code</label>
                    {{form.shipping_zip_code}}
                </p>
                <p class="shipping-weight">
                    <label for="id_shipping_weight">Weight</label>
                    {{form.shipping_weight}}
                </p>
                <p class="dimensions">
                    <label for="">Dimensions</label>
                    {{form.shipping_length}}
                    <label for=""></label>
                    {{form.shipping_width}}
                    <label for=""></label>
                    {{form.shipping_height}}
                </p>
            </div>
            <button class="submit-btn active-button">Submit Listing</button>
        </form>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="">
                <button class="active-button">Close</button>
                <img src="{% static 'listing/images/example-img.png' %}">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="spacer"></div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Much more simple than I had assumed.  Just needed to add 'value="{{ form.field_name.value }}"' to each input.

```
<input type="text" class="foo" value="{{ form.field_name.value }}"/>
```

I also found that each django template tag was being saved.  Replacing each `<input>` tag with the django `{{ form.field_name }}` variable also solved the problem.